# Send query parameters over with an array

Tags: php

I have a class `Pagination` with a method that counts the total number of articles. When I instantiate the class, I explicitly type the sql query and give him the parameters. Here is an example:

```
$pagination = new Pagination(self::DATABASE_FORUM_TOPICS, $this->currentPage, self::TOPICS_IN_CATEGORY, [
    'query' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM ' . self::DATABASE_FORUM_TOPICS . ' WHERE title LIKE ?',
    'params' => "%$keyWord%"
]);
```

The method that handles the query runs it and returns the result:

```
return $this->db->getRows($this->query['query'], [$this->query['params']]);
```

Everything works perfect, however, for this particular case (for searching articles) I want not only to count the results that match title but also by content, in other words I want to change to:

```
'SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM ' . self::DATABASE_FORUM_TOPICS . ' WHERE title LIKE ? OR content LIKE ?'
```

But how do I pass the second parameter in `'params' => "%$keyWord%"` ?

Edit: 
Pagination class.

```
    public function __construct(string $table, $currentPage = 1, $perPage, $query = [])
{
    $this->db = Database::getInstance();
    $this->currentPage = $currentPage;
    $this->perPage = $perPage;
    $this->table = $table;
    $this->query = $query;

    $getTotalRows = $this->countResultsFromTable();
    $getTotalRows = $getTotalRows[0]->count;
    $this->total = ceil($getTotalRows / $this->perPage);
}

public function countResultsFromTable()
{
    if(empty($this->query))
    {
        return $this->db->getRows("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM $this->table");
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->db->getRows($this->query['query'], [$this->query['params']]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add information about what pagination class you use and/or what system you're building this upon.. Just from the assumption I think you pass those parameters as an array ["%keyword1%", "%keyword2%"].

Comment: It's my own class and I am not using a framework or anything. Yes this was the idea to pass multiple parameters but the query is throwing `Invalid parameter number`. I edited my post with the entire Pagination class if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: extend your call to

```
$pagination = new Pagination(self::DATABASE_FORUM_TOPICS, $this->currentPage, self::TOPICS_IN_CATEGORY, [
    'query' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM ' . self::DATABASE_FORUM_TOPICS . ' WHERE title LIKE ? AND content LIKE ?',
    'title' => "%$keyWord%",
    'content' => $CONTENT
]);
```

and the query evaluation to

```
return $this->db->getRows($this->query['query'],
  [$this->query['title'], $this->query['content']]
);
```

If you don't want to change the Pagination class, append the content to the query before instantiating the Pagination:

```
$pagination = new Pagination(self::DATABASE_FORUM_TOPICS, $this->currentPage, self::TOPICS_IN_CATEGORY, [
    'query' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM ' . self::DATABASE_FORUM_TOPICS . ' WHERE title LIKE ? AND content LIKE "%' . your_escaping_function($content) . '%"',
    'title' => "%$keyWord%"
]);
```

Comment: I can't. The pagination class is used for other things (like ordering most recenty news, etc) that require sorting only by one parameter (by id for example). I need a different solution.

Comment: Okay, but as you insert the query anyways, you could write whatever needs to be appended to the query there.... will atttach it to my answer